# Dependency injection for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, dependency-injection, structuremap

I normally use StructureMap.dll (from MvcContrib) for dependency injection in .NET.

Is there an equivalent for Silverlight, or any tools anyone uses? I can do it by hand, obviously, and it's not difficult. But I wondered if there was something formalised like StructureMap but for Silverlight.

Comment: Ninject is good for MVC and that's it. Documentation is terrible at best. It so poorly supported that I would not use it in any application. Castle and Ninject are the absolute worst in documentation and incomplete examples on the web. They really should stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ninject does.  Some resources:

http://jonas.follesoe.no/2008/07/24/youcard-re-visited-implementing-dependency-injection-in-silverlight/

Comment: After looking into Ninject, it looks like exactly what I'm after so thanks again

Answer (score 1):

AutoFAC does as well (and is faster than NInject according to benchmarks I've seen).

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I wrote a [tutorial on using Ninject in Silverlight with MVVM](http://www.timmykokke.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-mvvm-ninject-and-silverlight/). The tutorial explains how to use Ninject. It describes some of its basic features like setting up the bindings in different ways and using constructor incjection. The tutorials has examples on how to use a ViewModelLocator to resolve objects from Ninject when using bindings.

I personally use Ninject most often.